# How to report if I found someone created a invalid tag?

Tags: support, tags

I just found someone created a new tag. But I am sure the created tag is not valid. It has a typo. If the typo is fixed then the tag is already exist. How can I report to fix this?

Comment: You have a link? Should be easy enough to correct. If that's the only question with that particular tag, removing it will automatically delete the tag after at most 24 hours.

Comment: You can also edit the question, remove the invalid tag and add the correct one.  The invalid tag will automatically be deleted when there are no questions with that tag.

Comment: here it is:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysq

Comment: Done. If nobody creates new questions with that tag, it will be automatically cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to report anything. All you need to do is remove the bogus tag from all questions. A garbage collection routine will kick in to remove unused tags.